# Jupyter Notebook freezes when rerunning cell asking for user input

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I put the following Python code in a Jupyter notebook cell, it asks for the user's input:

```
var = input('Enter something: ')
print(var)
```

However, when I rerun the cell while it's asking for input, the code doesn't get rerun, because the kernel was still 'busy' asking for the user's input.

How do I overcome this? It's a little annoying having to interrupt the kernel and rerun the code every time I make a test change.

Comment: did you try pressing enter?

Comment: Before rerunning the code? I could do that but it's more of an issue in the program I'm making—I can't just get rid of the prompt by pressing enter. My example was meant to be a [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example), which is the smallest amount of code that shows you what the problem is

Comment: If you're not going to use the input for anything why not just comment it out for now? Or just press enter

Comment: @Bugbeeb Imagine while you are writing a comment in SO, you decided to press F5 to reload but SO didn't reload because it was waiting for you to enter a comment. And now you have to close the browser and reopen it to continue using the site. It's the same scenario.

Comment: Maybe someone has a creative answer for you, but pure python running on a jupyter notebook kernel has to run on a single thread through the interpreter, so a user input prompt is similar to having a loop run meaning nothing else will be executed until the loop is broken

Comment: Is there any way to break this loop and just stop the program from running? My program is a series of interactive prompts, so there are many inputs that the user needs to give